# Transfer files from local machine to remote server using cifs plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cifs

I am trying to move files created by a Jenkins job to a CIFS shared directory (that's a bunch of Precompiled files of an asp.net web application).

After Jenkins job succeed, I get the log below with a *SUCCESS* status but without any file moved to the remote server. Can anyone suggest me what could be the reason of this?

> CIFS: Connecting from host [LocalHostName]
>
> CIFS: Connecting with configuration [DEPLOYMENT SERVER] ...
>
> CIFS: Disconnecting configuration [DEPLOYMENT SERVER] ...
>
> CIFS: Transferred 0 file(s) Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: which plug-in are you using to move your files ? The `remote server` you have mentioned above is it a jenkins server ?

Comment: i am using publish over cifs plug-in. The remote server is a windows server 2012 to which i am trying to send precompiled files of my .net web app from my local system. Jenkins is installed in my local machine and i am accessing it through localhost url.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How is your configuration in the general settings of Jenkins under the CIFS section? Does the "test" succeed? (btw `[, ]+` was already my default value)…  Also in which conf did you put the subdirectories, general or job? (`smb://server/share/subdirs`). Also also, did you use backslash, double backslash of slash separators?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom and solved the problem by filling the field `pattern separator` in the `advanced` section of the transfer set. I filled in `[, ]+`.
IMHO this is a bug, because the `Publish Over SSH Plugin` is filling in this pattern automatically and the `Publish Over CIFS Plugin` should do this also.